# Displaying data from local JSON based on a condition in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I wanted to know how to display the data by reading a local json. In a row having 4 columns, 2 columns are coming from 1 array and 2 are coming from a different array.

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>IT</th>
    <th>IT User</th>
    <th>CT</th>
    <th>CT User</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="currency">Type A</td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

    <td class="currency">Type B</td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
    <td class="currency"></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

JSON:

```
    {  
   "intr_liab":[  
      {  
     "ty":"typeA",
     "it":"100",
     "ct":"200"
  },
  {  
     "ty":"typeAITUser",
      "it":"300",
      "ct":"400"
  },
  {  
     "ty":"typeB",
      "it":"500",
      "ct":"600"
  },
  {  
     "ty":"typeBITUser",
     "it":"700",
     "ct":"800"
   }
 ]
}
```

So data in the table should come as:

```html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>IT</th>
        <th>IT User</th>
        <th>CT</th>
        <th>CT User</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="currency">Type A</td>
        <td class="currency">100</td>
        <td class="currency">300</td>
        <td class="currency">200</td>
        <td class="currency">400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        
        <td class="currency">Type B</td>
        <td class="currency">500</td>
        <td class="currency">700</td>
        <td class="currency">600</td>
        <td class="currency">800</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Please refer this Plunker for more clarity:
https://plnkr.co/edit/USt7nXmwCTRcCfOx8sma

Comment: You need to build your table with `ng-repeat`

Comment: _2 columns are coming from 1 array and 2 are coming from a different array_ -- where are these arrays? I can just see one array in your example.

Comment: @31piy I meant to say multiple objects.

Comment: @Zooly Can you demonstrate in Plunker?

Comment: What's the logic for deciding the type?

Answer (score -1):

Please replace the HTML code with following. I hope it will help you.

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>IT</th>
        <th>IT User</th>
        <th>CT</th>
        <th>CT User</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="item in intLiab">
        <td class="currency">{{item.ty}}</td>
        <td class="currency">{{item.it}}</td>
        <td class="currency"></td>
        <td class="currency">{{item.ct}}</td>
        <td class="currency"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Please comment if you need more specific answer.

Comment: Please read his expectation. Not the same result. It should be only 2 rows containing value of typeA and typeB

Comment: Hi @Zooly, I just opened a chain for a specific question from the answer I was given, and I am waiting for his response. I wish you could wait for a moment before down by answer. Thank you.

Comment: This answer is relevant, he should just add a ngIf condition that's all...

Comment: @AlexisToby This is not correct, I need the data something like this
         IT IT User CT CT User
Type A 100  300  200  400 
Type B 500  700          600  800

Comment: @AlexisToby I have updated my question. Please run the code snippet to check how the data should come.

Comment: Is there any possibility for you to modify the JSON data?

Comment: We need static keys to write dynamic looping function. Eg:   `$scope.intLiab = [
  {
    "ty": "typeA",
    "it": "100",
    "ct": "200",
    "typeUser": {
      "it": "300",
      "ct": "400"
    }
  },
  {
    "ty": "typeB",
    "it": "500",
    "ct": "600",
    "typeUser": {
      "it": "700",
      "ct": "800"
    }
  }
];`